# "empty" IllegalArgumentException with nested JSF h:panelGroups and f:ajax

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm having problems updating an inner nested `h:panelGroup` element using `f:ajax`. I have minimized my problem into following example:

```
<h:form id="someForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="wrapper">
        <h:panelGroup id="content">
            Some Content
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:commandLink
        action="#{bean.changeContent()}"
        value="Do Something">
        <f:ajax render=":someForm:wrapper:content"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

When i try to open the page, the `findComponent` method throws an `IllegalArgumentException` with no further information:

```
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/view/group/invitation/testCase.xhtml] 
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrapper
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:655)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.getResolvedId(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.appendIds(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:292)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.buildAjaxCommand(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.getScript(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:89)
...
```

I looked into the implementation and found following section that was causing the Exception:

```
...
result = findComponent(base, segments[i], (i == 0));
// the first element of the expression may match base.id
// (vs. a child if of base)
if (i == 0 && result == null && segments[i].equals(base.getId())) {
    result = base;
}
if (result != null && (!(result instanceof NamingContainer)) && length > 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(segments[i]);
}
...
```

I debugged the program, the component is found (by the first line of the code above), so my only conclusion is that `h:panelGroup` is not an instance of `NamingContainer`, but after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/cannot-find-component-with-expression-foo-referenced-from-bar-fajax-con/8644762#8644762) and checking the generated HTML for other examples my understanding was that a `h:panelGroup` IS a naming container. However, when i remove the wrapper and tell the ajax element to update the `content` `panelGroup` directly, no exception is thrown. I probably don't fully understand the method that JSF uses to search through the elements, I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me why this tiny example behaves this way.
I am using Mojarra 2.2.0 on GlassFish 4.0

Comment: *"and checking the generated HTML for other examples my understanding was that a h:panelGroup IS a naming container"* can you elaborate more how you came up to this conclusion? This is namely wrong.

Comment: i thought so because the rendered HTML contained an element with its id="someForm:content" and thought that the "content" part was rendered because it was a named container. However, then the "wrapper" part should have been rendered too, of course. I now understand how it works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to update/render a component from same `h:form` you don't need to attach the form id to component id.
So in you case

```
<f:ajax render="content"/>
```

would do the job for you.

And `h:panelGroup` is not a NamingContainer component. So you dont need to refer the inner components of `h:panelGroup` by nesting its id.

So `<h:panelGroup id="content">` can be referred from out side form with just `someForm:content`.
`someForm:wrapper:content` is wrong thing. This is the reason you are getting the exception.

You can always find out the generated component id on browser by Right Click and  Inpect element.

Comment: Thanks! i was confused that i could specify a h:panelGroup for an ajax update although it is not a naming container. Everythings is working now.